# How to disable boot from USB?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, bios, usb-storage

My computer always tries to boot from external USB HDD. I have tried removing all other options from the boot priorities list, but it still boots to my external HDD.
I have an Asus M4A88TD-V EVO/USB3. Any solutions?

Comment: What is this “tried enabling the boot only from the SSD disk.” These settings are in the BIOS. And you don’t enable the system to boot from a single device. Instead you DISABLE devices you don’t want to boot from.

Comment: Open BIOS > Boot > Boot Device Priority and you'll find out that "Removable Dev." is the "1st Boot Device" (in the absence of *any* bootable "removable device" it boots from 2nd device which is likely to be "Hard Drive".

Comment: @Appleoddity The BIOS has the ability to set up to three devices from which to boot.
I left only one enabled.

Comment: @MichaelBay I think I already did that. The BIOS has the ability to set up to three devices from which to boot.
I left only one enabled, the main SSD. There's any other thing to set?

Comment: Is that the "1st Boot Device"? I have the manual - chapter 3.8.1

Comment: @MichaelBay I set 1st Boot device SSD EVO840 2nd Device disabled, also 3rd device. I can take a photo if you need but I'm writing from that PC so it going to take me a couple of minutes to do it.

Comment: And with that configuration it tries to boot from the external HDD? What happens exactly when that drive is connected during the boot process? Please [edit] and update you question accordingly.

Comment: @MichaelBay It seems like it tries because the external HDD link blinks and the screen is black. If I unplug the external HDD and reset it boot from SSD and Windows works ok, like nothing was happened.

Comment: Ypu may try updating the BIOS to the last version. The problem isn't it trying to boot from the external drive, the problem is that it doesn't boot with it connected. Very different situations. I've seen the same happening in some PCs and with different USB devices.

Comment: @MichaelBay I already update it a few years ago to version 2301. So there's no solution. I must unplug the external HDD before turn on the PC.

Comment: I'm afraid so. It's a minor inconvenience though.

Comment: Yes, I have another ASUS motherboard 970 PRO GAMING/AURA that the clocks goes about 15Hs to the future when is in standby.